# Accessing grandparent ng-repeat object when the parent ng-repeat is another object

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to access the grandparent object of a `ng-repeat` item in angular.

I am struggling to make this happen.

As you can see from below I want to display the text of the parent object.

This is a watered down version, I am looking for a way to make it work like the top example or a reason as to why it will not work.

Here is the DOM.

```
<div ng-app ng-controller="MyCtrl">
 <!-- this is the one i cannot get working -->
  <div>
    <div class="copyData" ng-repeat="copy in copyDatabase">
    <div ng-repeat="header in masterHeaders">
      <div ng-repeat="test in copy.Translations">
        set 1: {{test.LanguageAbreviation}}
      </div>
  </div>

  <div>
  <!-- this one does work but i need the item from the masterHeaders -->
    <div class="copyData" ng-repeat="copy in copyDatabase">
    <!-- <div ng-repeat="header in masterHeaders"> -->
      <div ng-repeat="test in copy.Translations">
        set 2 : {{test.LanguageAbreviation}}
      </div>
      <!--</div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
```

Here is the JSON Object

```
   function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.copyDatabase = {
    "data": {
      "Language": "English",
      "Translations": [{
        "LanguageID": 308,
        "LanguageName": "Arabic - Libya",
        "LanguageAbreviation": "ar-LY",
        "AvailableLanguages": [{
          "ID": 308,
          "Name": "Arabic - Libya"
        }]
      }, {
        "LanguageID": 307,
        "LanguageName": "Arabic - Egypt",
        "LanguageAbreviation": "ar-EG",
        "AvailableLanguages": [{
          "ID": 307,
          "Name": "Arabic - Egypt"
        }]
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

I have also made a JS fiddle for you guys.

http://jsfiddle.net/u7hk0qvj/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to have the :

```
$scope.masterHeaders = {
  "home": "home",
  "contact": "contact"
}
```

Object also in the control, If angular does not find the object it will not load any of the DOM elements In the `ng-repeat`.

Working fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/u7hk0qvj/8/

Answer (score 0):

Seeing your jsfiddle, you have a base mistake, Angular is not finding your MyCtrl. You need to declare as an angular component.

You are creating a global funcion MyCtrl, but this isn't inside the angular context, for example:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('GreetingController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.greeting = 'Hola!';
}]);
```

You can see more info [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

Comment: Hi Kalamarico, thank you for your feed back, unfortunately thier was a type-o error with my data object , please see latest jsFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/u7hk0qvj/5/. I hope you can better see my example